# Can an adverb be the subject in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

Does 'carefully' function as the subject in the below sentence?

Carefully does it.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. What has your research turned up? Do you have an example sentence from a newspaper where you've seen this?

Comment: Also ***Easy** does it!* for an even more common "imperative". And *Handsome is as handsome does* for a "set phrase" aphorism.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Where is the adverb in the handsome example? Wouldn't it need to be "handsomely is as ....."?

Comment: There's an [ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/189916/nice-and-easy-does-the-trick-vs-nicely-and-easily-does-the-trick) about "nice and easy does it", but it's not very conclusive. I suspect there's some elision going on (maybe "doing it carefully does it", where the latter "do" means [bring about](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/do) or something similar), but there seem different theories.

Comment: In the common phrase "easy does it", easy is used as an adverb. The subject is omitted. "Carefully does it" will probably end up functioning the same way.

Comment: @WS2: Okay - so "handsome" is *in principle* an adjective, n*ot an adverb. I was just alluding to the fact that crude categories such as "adverb, adjective, noun" aren't necessarily helpful when analysing certain "valid" utterances.

Comment: Yes, there's almost certainly deletion here, leaving what is probably best just considered an extragrammatical idiom.

Comment: _Carefully_ functions as the subject in the first sentence in the original post. "Does 'carefully' function as the subject in the sentence below?" The quote marks are irrelevant, since they don't occur in speech. So, yes. Just about **anything** can be the subject in English.

Comment: I hear carefully does it as the word carefully in the question sentence (Does 'carefully' function...).  Both refer to the word 'carefully' as the dictionary word. Proceed according to that word.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand "handsome is as handsome does" as actually meaning "handsomeness is as handsomeness does". The adjective is being used as an abbreviation for the corresponding noun. And similar substitutions can work for adverbs.

Comment: @JohnLawler - You convinced me.  How about transferring your comment to an Answer?

Comment: Questions that can be answered in 3 lines don't need Official Answers.

Answer (score 1):

Adverbs do not function as subjects.  [Adverbs](https://editorsmanual.com/articles/adverbs/) modify adjectives, verbs, other adverbs, phrases, clauses, or entire sentences.  While adverbs can be placed at the start of a sentence, they still act on the sentence proper.

For example, in the following sentence:

> Unfortunately, I forgot to tie my shoe.

"Unfortunately" is an adverb that passes judgement on the sentence, "I forgot to tie my shoe".  The adverb acts on the whole sentence, and the subject is "I."  A different version of this sentence is below:

> Forgot to tie my shoe.

This version implies "I" at the beginning, since the shoe is "mine."  This is an example of an [implicit subject](https://editorsmanual.com/articles/sentence-implied-subject-grammar/).  Phrases with implicit subjects are used in conversation and/or as imperatives, as in "Thank you" really meaning "[I] thank you," or "Do it" really meaning "[You] Do it."

In the case of "Carefully does it," "Carefully" is describing "does." "does" implies "he does," "she does," "it does," or proper-name-"does" (e.g "Jack does").  The phrase would be more clear in written form as "Carefully he does it."  But if we are dealing with an implied subject, then there is a good chance this phrase is being used in spoken English, and the subject need not be explicitly named.

Answer (score 0):

John Lawler wrote an interesting comment, but declined to transfer it to an answer, so I'll do the transferring, with some reformatting, as I found it interesting.

> Yes, *carefully* functions as the subject in the first sentence in the original post. In fact just about anything can be the subject in English.

Comment: I'm not opposed to this answer, but I wish that a reason were given. For example, in the sentence "easy goes it" (not a perfect analogy, I admit), I think that the subject would be "it". I therefore think that we should explain why "it" isn't the subject in "carefully does it".

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - Your best bet is to ping John about that.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's the subject. "Carefully does it" is an idiom with the imperative meaning of "Do it carefully".

Comment: @BillJ I'm OK if someone wants to say that the phrase is idiomatic and not worry too much about the internal struture. It would be kind of interesting to know the etymology, though, because that might shed some light on how the phrase was originally structured and why it seems so strange nowadays.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - Isn't "Easy does it" pretty ordinary (not strange sounding)?

Comment: @aparente001 Yes, it's a common idiom. I only meant that it seems strange when you try to parse its structure.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - Agreed.  When I think of a similar expression in Spanish, I'm not sure I agree with John.  To me it seems like an adverb modifying a verb, not a subject.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "carefully" is doing anything; the literal semantic meaning is more like,

> (if you do what you are doing) carefully, it will be adequate.

Compare "that does it" for this meaning of does.

I think you could call this a [phatic expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phatic_expression); they often drift away from their literal meaning as well: "(are) you alright?" in British English is a standard greeting, whereas in American English it will be interpreted as an actual question

Answer (score -1):

According to at least Merriam Webster an adverb can function as subject, and I am saying this because under the adverb section in the definition of the word "There" it also gave this sentence example "there is where I disagree with you"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).